# Linking error when compiling Allegro example

Tags: c++, allegro

I am currently learning about game development tools and decided to use Allegro and OpenGL for starters. I've run into some problems in getting examples to compile though. It seems the `allergro.h` library isn't linking correctly. Some web searching didn't help.

Here's my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro.h>

int main()
{
    allegro_init();
    //...
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

I'm running this command to compile it:

`g++ allegroTemplate.cpp -o allegroTemplate`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
/tmp/ccbpAXIY.o: In function `main':
allegroTemplate.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `_install_allegro_version_check'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running this in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

> g++ allegroTemplate.cpp -o allegroTemplate

You aren't linking with Allegro. With Allegro 4, it's recommended to use the `allegro-config` command, like

```
g++ souce.cpp -o game $(allegro-config --libs)
```

If you are just getting started, you really should take a look at Allegro 5 instead. It has integrated OpenGL support and is actively being developed, unlike Allegro 4.